# PHP encode e-mail address

Tags: php, hash, encode

I need a way in `PHP` to encode an e-mail address only using `a-zA-Z0-9` so basically encoded without any special characters, but then be able to decode it back to the original.

Example:

```
 john+doe@mydomain.com => ENCODE => n6bvJjdh7w6QbdVB373483ydbKus7Qx
 n6bvJjdh7w6QbdVB373483ydbKus7Qx => DECODE => john+doe@mydomain.com
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Take a look at this just for fun: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Doesn't `rawurlencode()` work?

Comment: `rawurlencode()` and `urlencode()` do not work, since they don't escape `.` I can't have periods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a web safe base64 encode:

```
// encode
$email_encoded = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($email), '+/', '-_'), '=');

// decode
$email_decoded = base64_decode(strtr($email_encoded, '-_', '+/'));
```

It converts the `+` and `/` from the base64 alphabet in the more harmless `-` and `_`. The encoding step also removes the trailing `=` characters when needed.

Comment: What does strstr with `+/` and `-_` do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: @Justin It converts each `+` into `-` and each `/` into `_`.

Comment: Where there ever be + and / returned from base64 encode though? I thought it returns `a-zA-Z0-9=` only. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin there's a reason it's called base64 and not base62 :) the = is padding btw, and it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow the equal sign, you can use [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Another option is [`bin2hex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php)