# PHP hashing using BCRYPT adds unwanted character

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

When using the BCRYPT function is PHP, it produces a **, of course this is as expected. However it also adds unwanted characters such " . " (DOTS) when hashing, which again is to be expected.

I would like to know if there is a hashing function which I can use in PHP which doesn't create a hash which dots in it or if I can tell the hash function in some way not to create a hash with dots.

I am using this create a unique link key hash.

```
$passHash = password_hash($email, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want not want dots; what's so special about it that you don't want the dots? You won't be able to omit it, I can tell you that right now and it will cause havoc.

Comment: As I am using it as Link later on in the browser and the link has a dot at the end of it, the browser doesn't put it in, weirdly

Comment: your question is getting more unclear, why would you want to use it as a link?

Comment: Apologies, For instance if i want to create a link like this:                             $pwdLink = "www.blahhh.co.uk/customer/forgot/resetLink.php?key=".$passHash.""; the hash is then used to make the link unique which is then stored in the DB. When the user open the link with the unique hash it is then looked up in the DB to see if the link is still valid

Comment: $passHash = urlencode(password_hash($email, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

Comment: In general, you shouldn't have any issues using it as a query string value if you url encode it. I don't know if I'd use password_hash for this, personally, but it should work.

Comment: you're not doing it right and that should have been part of the question.

Comment: thanks, if it not the right way can you advise how you would do it?

Comment: I would probably use md5 or sha for this tho.

Comment: okay thanks will do. thanks for your help

Comment: @harry4912 is this for email verification purposes? If so, there are a few methods to use but something like this `$code=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);` may be enough. There are encoding/decoding methods also.

Comment: This Q&A although not directly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086970/php-encode-e-mail-address shows a way to encode and decode a string, should you want to go that route.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks I will give that ago now. Cheers

Comment: you're welcome @harry

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner worked perfect you are a LEGEND!! cheers

Comment: @harry glad to hear it worked out for you Harry, *cheers*

Comment: @harry4912 curious though; did you use this method? `$code=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes I did. should be unique enough shouldn't it

Comment: @harry4912 yes it will be enough.

Comment: @harry4912 I posted an answer below and added another method if you want to look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that this is for verification purposes, using the following is ample to use:

```
$code=substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);
```

The [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function does create a unique string, sure, but it just wasn't designed for doing verification purposes as you're doing now.

There's also this method that I use from time to time:

```
$token = substr(hash('sha512', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 50);
```

which will create an even longer and more precise token when using [`microtime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

***Disclaimer:*** This is for random token generation and not related to password hashing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, have used $token = substr(hash('sha512', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 50);
and works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: @harry4912 Welcome, glad to have been of help Harry, *cheers*

Comment: You should make it more clear that this is for random token generation and *not* related to password hashing, otherwise you're going to attract more knee-jerk downvotes. :P

Comment: @Sammitch that was just a reference comparison.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not a secure way to generate random tokens, `random_bytes` should be used instead.

Comment: @d3L what are you talking about? This has nothing to do with security at all. You tell me how that is, because I would really love to hear what you have to say about it, and in detail. I'm all ears.

Comment: @d3L addendum to my above comment. [`random_bytes()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) is PHP 7 exclusive, so it's not everybody who's using that version nor do all web servers offer it. Just thought that you and the good folk looking around might like to know.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, if you don't care about security  ;-) There are plenty of resources online (for example https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40310/generating-an-unguessable-token-for-confirmation-e-mails).

Comment: @d3L this question has nothing to do with security. Why don't you just put your money where your mouth is rather than your downvote and submit an answer. It's a free world.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm aware of that. There are workarounds though, see my provided link. I just wanted to leave this here in case someone else stumbles upon this answer and doesn't know that `mt_rand()` and friends are actually evil.

Comment: @d3L Well that was fun. Now, about that link you referenced [Generating an unguessable token for confirmation e-mails](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40310/34623) mentions not to use `rand()` or `mt_rand()` sure,... *BUT,* here's the clincher. What I have in both lines of code, `mt_rand()` isn't being used on its own, there are 2-4 other functions used in conjunction with it and will never be guessed as an mt_rand/rand generated string. You almost had me there.

Comment: @d3L you need to retract your downvote. I'm just wondering why you didn't think/look twice before doing that, which IMHO was uncalled for.