# Proper way to set "unsubscribe" link from a sent email to users?

Tags: php

I've been using a way to unsuscribe people from a website newsletter, and that works when a user replies to an email with the word "unsuscribe".

But I want to change that so people only click a link in the email they received, redirect to my website and succesfuly unsuscribe that user. But this way makes me afraid of people being able to play with the url, write different emails and unsuscribe random people.

I know it sounds crazy but I'm a bit paranoic with the security stuff.

I have no code since I have no idea how to achieve this the proper way, meaning no playing with the url parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: ^ or you could encrypt the email address in the link with a key stored on the site, and unencrypted once its clicked

Comment: encode the email and use an additional one-way hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign the email with [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

```
$token = hash_hmac('sha256', 'email@example.com', 'secret-server-key');
```

Then pass that to the email template, so your unsubscribe link would be somthing like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/unsubscribe?email=email@example.com&token=abcec5cdca4d760d34e8c02107ae68f251f08aaa9dd14956c2f0ab84a33f6441">
```

Then when the user clicks it, sign the email parameter, if the tokens match then continue.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['token']) && 
    $_GET['token'] === hash_hmac('sha256', $_GET['email'], 'secret-server-key')
) {
  // lagit
}
```

This is safe as long as you never share the `secret-server-key`.

---

Edit:

Taking on the comments from @FunkFortyNiner

You could sign and encode the email into a single token. Essentially just like JWT now but without the json ;p

So your token would look like: `ZW1haWxAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20.abcec5cdca4d760d34e8c02107ae68f251f08aaa9dd14956c2f0ab84a33f6441` but would involve alot more code in checking. If your really paronoid perhaps its worth it.

```
<?php
$email = 'email@example.com';

function base64url_encode($str) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($str), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($str) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($str, '-_', '+/'));
}

$token = base64url_encode($email).'.'.hash_hmac('sha256', $email, 'secret-server-key');

// mock got token
$_GET['token'] = $token;

// when checking
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
    $tok = explode('.', $_GET['token']);

    // check token parts
    if (count($tok) !== 2) {
        // not valid token
        throw new \Exception('Invalid token!');
    }

    // check email segment
    if (!isset($tok[0]) || !filter_var(base64url_decode($tok[0]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // not valid email
        throw new \Exception('Invalid token!');
    }

    $email = base64url_decode($tok[0]);

    if ($tok[1] !== hash_hmac('sha256', $email, 'secret-server-key')) {
        // failed verification
        throw new \Exception('Invalid token!');
    }

    //
    echo 'Its lagit!';

    // do somthing with $email
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tcqk8

Comment: thanks, I've never used the hash_hmac() before and I'm finding it hard to understand in the php manual. What sould the 'secret-server-key' is exactly? Should I add a new column to the DB table with this?

Comment: `secret-server-key` should be a config constant which should be strong, so you could pass in a .pem string if your paranoid. This is fundamentally how JWT's work, if you made it dynamic or assigned to the user you would need to look it up first, and adds additional overhead for no gain.

Comment: I'd encode the email also and especially when under HTTP.

Comment: Basically, your signing the email with a key, the resulting hash is specific to the key and the data, an attacker could change the email but it would not produce the same hash, the attacker would need to know the secret to produce the same hash which you dont share.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Then you would need to store the hash of the email as to associate it back to the email.

Comment: it's not being hashed, it's to be encoded then decoded after @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this is what I was talking about https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087036/1415724

Comment: Like base64/91 url encode etc? Yeah you could also do that, but it does not add much security, just obscurity ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if someone were to start phishing around, then it should by all means, encoded. This along with the additional key. It's not the best, but it does work.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this actually looks great! And basically looks out of the box, I'll just give this a try.. I hope not to have any kind of security "leak", although is just for the unsuscribe link but I take too serious the security in my projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen the follwing:
The link in the email to unsubscribe.php
The user keys in his email again, confirms it in his email box.
I see, the newsletter app at [www.mywebtodo.net](http://www.mywebtodo.net) could be a bit better.